# Big Oh notation? What does it mean here?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am going to ask my question through an example.

> Use big Oh notation to write a 2rd Taylor polynomial for $f(x) = e^x$ at $a = 0$ with error term.

I already "know" the answer is just $P_3 = 1 +x +x^2/2 + O(|x|^3)$ from my previous experience with other math classes.

Now from what i have been reading online, a function can only be "big Oh" of another function. So can someone tell me what the question is actually asking here? Is it asking me (and how actually is it telling me this?) to show that the 2nd order Taylor polynomial is "big oh" of the error term?

Comment: Seems like you forgot the $\frac12$ in front of $x^2$.

Comment: Don't you think it is just a representation in asymptotic analysis where it tells the function beyond which which one can overlook while approximating sequence of functions as it will not really affect the approximated function. Its used differently than analysis of algorithms when limit is considered approaching zero as in algorithms, its always about increasing input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the difference of functions: $f(x)-P_3(x)=O(|x|^3)$.

"...to show that the 2nd order Taylor polynomial is "big oh" of the error term?"

The difference $f-P_3$ **is** the error term, and the error term is $O(|x|^3)$.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: The **function** $f-P_3$ is $O(|x|^3)$.